# C# printing to network printer is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I have a print server Ps01 Hosting a print queue Pq01, I found it takes around 10 seconds to get the job submitted to the print server for a simple document.

```
            pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
            PaperSize ps = new PaperSize();
            ps.RawKind = 9;//A4
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps;

            pd.OriginAtMargins = false;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution = new PrinterResolution() { X = 300, Y = 300 };
            pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;

            pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = @"\\Ps01\Pq01";
            pd.Print();
```

However I found that If I create a LocalPort i.e. LocalPort01 on the Pc with the actual address of \\Ps01\Pq01, and change the PrinterName to LocalPort01, the print job will spool a lot faster ~200ms.

What is actually happening here? Is there any explanation for this? Is it possible to achieve the same performance without mapping it with a LocalPort? Thanks.

Comment: Is this in a corporate network? Is it a large organisation?

Comment: Yes, at least they are in different subnet but in same ad.